# why omnet++ version 5 ned file suddenly corrupted

Tags: omnet++

Suddenly the ned file seems corrupted for simulations that uses [] notation to add an arbitrary number of modules. for example, in tictoc10.ned,  tic[6]: Txc10 shows tic[6] on the design tap rather than six tic modules. i re-installed omnet++ and once i open the ned file for the tictoc tutorial the ned is corrupted and this includes all other examples. see the attached figure [tictoc10.ned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdWah.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. The design view in the IDE never actually instantiates the submodules. i.e. you will never see 10 icons if you define a submodule[10]. The runtime does this of course, but not the IDE.

In other words: The IDE shows the structure of the NED file, while the runtime shows the modules that were actually created.

Comment: thanks for the response, but in this case how to set the generated modules into specific locations in the runtime?

Comment: You should NOT use the display string positions as the physical location for your modules. Those positions are there to arrange the modules in a neat way for displaying and not meant to actually used as a physical location (i.e. you should not calculate propagation delay etc based on them). The main reason: the simulation should produce the same result if it is run from Cmdenv, however Cmdenv does not understand the @displaystring properties. For example in INET, there is a separate module called (mobility) in the StandardHost which is responsible for the node placement.